# Use BindingSource() for a combobox with dictionary where key is string and value is list

Tags: c#, combobox, bindingsource

I don't have a lot of experience with BindingSource and I want my comboBox to be bind to a dictionary 
containing a string for key and a list of int as value.

But get the exception - {"Cannot bind to the new value member.\r\nParameter name: value"}

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>()
        {
            {"a", new List<int>{0,1}},
            {"b", new List<int>{3}},
            {"c", new List<int>{4,5,6}}
        };

        cbo1.DataSource = new BindingSource(dic, null);
        cbo1.DisplayMember = "Key";
        cbo1.ValueMember = "Value";
```

if instead of a List I use a Tuple, it works just fine.

can what i'm trying to do be done with a unfixed sized value?

Thank you

Comment: **Correction:** Bind the new `BindingSource` after setting both `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties. Make it the last line.

Comment: As @JQSOFT mentioned, always set the DataSource **after** you have set the DisplayMember (it's a semi-long story). I also suggest to use an stand-alone BindingSource object instead of writing `new BindingSource(dic, null);`. Of course you can cast `ComboBox.DataSource` to BindingSource, but since you may need that BindingSource, better have it readily accessible. If you don't need it, don''t use it. You can directly set the Dictionary as DataSource.

Comment: With *directly set the Dictionary as DataSource* I mean `cbo1.DataSource = dic.ToList();`. About the BindingSource: having it as a stand-alone object is also useful when setting the DataBindings of other *connected* (bound) objects (Controls or other, different, object), eventually.